# Processing a file on client side in Django?

Tags: reactjs, django

I want to build a web application where a user can upload a file, the file is processed and some result is shown to the user (for example the amount of lines of the file).

However, since the files might be confidential, the user does not want that the file is stored on the server side. So the file needs to be processed without storing it on the server.

Since I am familiar with Python, I wanted to create the website using Django (I want to learn it anyway). But as I understood, Django is a server framework, so is it even achievable using Django what I want to do? How?

Or do I need to use React and Django? Or only React?

Comment: You _could_ use Django, but if all of the work is done client-side in an SPA all it would be doing is serving static files. So why bother?

Comment: I am not quite sure where the web application is going in the future, so there might be more and more features and at some point it might be that an SPA won't do it anymore

Comment: YAGNI. If you do get there, maybe entirely new options will be available, why make the technology choice earlier than you need to.

Comment: You can achieve this functionality using Django without permanently storing the files on the server. To process a file without saving it, you can use an in-memory file storage, such as Python's io.BytesIO, and handle the processing directly in the view.

Comment: Thanks @LinusTux! But wouldn't this still violate the confidentiality of the processed file, as I still process it server side? So the user would have to "trust me" that I am deleting the file afterwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**:

- Completely possible, but it may be a more complex solution than is needed if this is the only requirement of the project.
- For pure client-side file manipulation, you would stick to pure client-side JavaScript code regardless of choice of Framework. So either a simple static site or a JS framework like Vue/React would be simpler.
- But if your users 'trust' that you won't save the file, then it is perfectly possible to do manipulation server-side with Django, and then return your file in an HTTP response without at any point saving the file or even touching a database.

---

**Long answer**:

I'll assume your users 'trust' the site, and show you some example Django code that takes a CSV file uploaded by a user and returns to the client the number of rows and columns in the file without saving the file at any point:

**forms.py**

```py
from django import forms

class CSVUploadForm(forms.Form):
    csv_file = forms.FileField(label='Select a CSV file')
```

**views.py**

```py
import csv
from io import StringIO
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import CSVUploadForm

def upload_csv(request):
    context = {'form': None, 'rows': None, 'columns': None}
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CSVUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            file = request.FILES['csv_file']
            content = file.read().decode('utf-8')
            csv_reader = csv.reader(StringIO(content))
            rows = 0
            cols = 0
            for row in csv_reader:
                rows += 1
                cols = max(cols, len(row))
            context['rows'] = rows
            context['columns'] = cols
    else:
        form = CSVUploadForm()
    
    context['form'] = form
    return render(request, 'app/upload_csv.html', context)
```

**urls.py**

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('upload_csv/', views.upload_csv, name='upload_csv'),
]
```

**Template** *(assumes you already have a base template)*

```html
{% extends "base/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <h2>Upload a CSV file</h2>
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
  </form>
  {% if rows and columns %}
    <div>
      <h3>Results:</h3>
      <p>Number of rows: {{ rows }}</p>
      <p>Number of columns: {{ columns }}</p>
    </div>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

---

**For point of comparison**, you could do exactly the same purely client-side with no server upload using just the following lines of vanilla JS in any framework, or even a static site:

```js
function processCSV(content) {
    const rows = content.split('\n');
    let rowCount = 0;
    let columnCount = 0;

    rows.forEach(row => {
        if (row.trim() !== '') {
            rowCount++;
            const columns = row.split(',');
            columnCount = Math.max(columnCount, columns.length);
        }
    });

    return { rowCount, columnCount };
}

document.getElementById('upload-form').addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const fileInput = document.getElementById('csv-file');
    const file = fileInput.files[0];
    if (!file) {
        alert('Please select a CSV file');
        return;
    }

    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (event) {
        const content = event.target.result;
        const { rowCount, columnCount } = processCSV(content);

        document.getElementById('rows').textContent = rowCount;
        document.getElementById('columns').textContent = columnCount;
        document.getElementById('results').style.display = 'block';
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
});
```

So choice is yours - totally doable if needed, but best choice depends on eventual complexity and how trusting your users are!